# designing a form for a Ruby on Rails application

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-5

Here's [a link](http://framebox.org/YqpY-CLNXJR) to a simple HTML form I designed. I am searching for the best way to create such an 'inline', using Ruby on Rails. Are there gems, or other tools to create such a kind of form?

What I really would like is a sort of speadsheet-like input with multiple rows that can be edited one at a time. Above that, scrolling and adding new lines when necessary. I think that CoffeeScript / JavaScript or simular tools could do these tricks!

This is something in the back of my head for quite some time now; I have searched for examples and / or tutorials, but so far I can not find something that really suits me. Any tip or example is welcome!

Thank you!

Comment: This is a CSS question rather than a rails one, it's a relatively straightforward form that just needs some styling.

Comment: It is a rails question, imho. Maybe I am not clear enough; what I would like to know, is there some kind of rails form_for set-up, or the likes, to render the input boxes horizontally? In almost all examples I have seen, the inputs are on separate rows.

Comment: There may well be a gem for this, but it could be overkill for you. Creating a form as per usual with rails helpers, and then adding a css rule like `input { display: inline; }` will make it display horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

Html --> Please check sample html code for horizontal form

```
<label>E-Mail:</label>
<input type="text" name="id" maxlength="30" value="" />
<label>Password:</label> 
<input type="text" name="pw" maxlength="30" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
```

Following code are the rails horizontal form

```
<%= f.label :email %>:
<%= f.text_field :email %>
<%= f.label :password %>:
<%= f.password_field :last_name %>
<%= f.submit %>
```

css -->

```
input,label {
     float:left;
     margin:5px;
    }
```

For Jsfiddle example [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HcppN/)